# First element always checked

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a code, when you click on a new task, the first one is crossed out, I can’t understand why.

[image]

[image]

When you click on a new task, the first one is crossed out, and the one I click on should be

```
<template>
<h4>Today Tasks</h4>  
<div class="tasks">
<div 
      class="task"
      :class="{ completed: task.isCompleted }"
      v-for="task in tasks"
      :key="task._id"
      @click="completedHandler(task._id)"
   >

  <div 
        class="round"
        :class="{ 
        business: task.type === 'business', 
        personal: task.type === 'personal',
        }"
        
        ></div>

    <span>{{task.name}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="add-task">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Название задачи" v-model="taskName" />
    <button @click="addTask">+</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      taskName: "",
      tasks: [{
        _id: "wadawdawdwa",
        name: "Create to do app in Vue js",
        isCompleted: false,
        type: "personal",
      }
      ]
    }
  },
    methods:{
      completedHandler:function(taskid){
        const currentTask=this.tasks.find((t)=> t._id=taskid);
        currentTask.isCompleted = !currentTask.isCompleted;
    },

    addTask: function(){
      this.tasks.push({
        _id: Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 7),
        name: this.taskName,
        isCompleted: false,
        type: "personal",
       });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Because in the `find` call, with `t._id=taskid` you are not testing equality but assigning a value. Use `==` instead.

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately it has nothing to do with the fact that after clicking on a new task, the first one is crossed out anyway, and not the one that was clicked

Comment: That's really interesting, because 1) logically that's the only part in the code which has anything to do with the problem (selecting the task after a click), 2) by fixing that typo it actually works: https://jsfiddle.net/juzraai/Lq7prmy1/3/

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked in the wrong place, now everything is clear, thank you

Comment: Initially thought of this place (        class="round"
        :class="{ 
        business: task.type === 'business', 
        personal: task.type === 'personal',
        }")
my carelessness)